# MVC Print Page break not working, contents are cut off

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I tried below code to break the page while printing however its not working, I learnt that the Page break won't work in nested div tags, I 'm not sure how to achieve this, basically I 'm trying to display images, so in a row there will be 4 or more than that based on the display size of screen however at the time of printing it should print 4 images in a row and the next 4 images should be printed in next page as if now while printing, the images and the contents are getting cut off, please help

```
     <div class='row small'>
        @foreach (var item in Model.BuyerList.ImageList)
        {

            <div class="card bg-light mb-3 mr-1 card-text-fixed-width" style='page-break-after:always'>
                <div class="img-control">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ImageUrl))
                    {
                        <img src="@item.ImageUrl" style="height:150px;" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <img src="~/AdTrack Images/NoProductImage.png" style="height:150px;" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
                    }
                      <div class="edit d-print-none">
                            <a data-toggle="modal"
                               data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.ItemId", "AdId":"@item.Header.Id"}'
                               class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="delete d-print-none">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.Id", "AdId":"@item.Id"}'
                               class="open-delete btn btn-primary" href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:15px;color:red" id="delete" name="delete"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="edit d-print-none">
                            <a data-toggle="modal"
                               data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.ItemId", "AdId":"@item.Header.Id"}'
                               class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Page @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)- @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Business)</div>
                    <div class="row mb-2 font-weight-bold">
                        <div class="col-md-6">Cut: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Number)</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">9-Box: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.BoxNumber)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-2 font-weight-bold">
                        <div class="col-md-4">Group @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Test)</div>
                        @*<div class="col-md-4">Div: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Division)</div>*@
                        <div class="col-md-4">Buyer @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Test)</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">Dept @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Department)</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
        }
        </div>
```

Comment: @PaTPH
you can add following properties on image 

img {
    page-break-before: auto; /* 'always,' 'avoid,' 'left,' 'inherit,' or 'right' */
    page-break-after: auto; /* 'always,' 'avoid,' 'left,' 'inherit,' or 'right' */
    page-break-inside: avoid; /* or 'auto' */
}

Comment: @RakeshKumar Its div with card and contents so obviously its not working

Comment: Any help on this Guyz?

Answer (score 0):

Add wrap `div` with `style='page-break-after:always'`.

```
<div class='row small'>
        @foreach (var item in Model.BuyerList.ImageList)
        {
            <div style='page-break-after:always'>
                <div class="card bg-light mb-3 mr-1 card-text-fixed-width" >
                    <div class="img-control">
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ImageUrl))
                        {
                            <img src="@item.ImageUrl" style="height:150px;" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img src="~/AdTrack Images/NoProductImage.png" style="height:150px;" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
                        }
                          <div class="edit d-print-none">
                                <a data-toggle="modal"
                                   data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.ItemId", "AdId":"@item.Header.Id"}'
                                   class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="delete d-print-none">
                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.Id", "AdId":"@item.Id"}'
                                   class="open-delete btn btn-primary" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:15px;color:red" id="delete" name="delete"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="edit d-print-none">
                                <a data-toggle="modal"
                                   data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.ItemId", "AdId":"@item.Header.Id"}'
                                   class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="font-weight-bold">Page @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)- @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Business)</div>
                        <div class="row mb-2 font-weight-bold">
                            <div class="col-md-6">Cut: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Number)</div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">9-Box: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.BoxNumber)</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-2 font-weight-bold">
                            <div class="col-md-4">Group @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Test)</div>
                            @*<div class="col-md-4">Div: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Division)</div>*@
                            <div class="col-md-4">Buyer @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Test)</div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">Dept @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Department)</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I achieved it using CSS. Simply add a css class and give it width in percentage. For example, 30% if you want to display 3 pictures or 19% if you want to display 4 and you can also set margin accordingly if you want spaces between the images. In this way, the images would resize themselves accordingly no matter what screen size is.

Example:

```
img {
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
}
```

Please refer to this code pen link also: https://codepen.io/alinaalam/pen/YeLqWm

Answer (score 0):

You may try using gridContainers, combined with css you can determine how many items you want displayed per row

```
<div class="gridContainer">
@foreach (var item in Model.BuyerList.ImageList)
        {
             <div class="grid-item">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ImageUrl))
                    {

                        <img src="@item.ImageUrl" style="height:150px;" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <img src="~/AdTrack Images/NoProductImage.png" style="height:150px;" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
                    }
                      <div class="edit d-print-none">
                            <a data-toggle="modal"
                               data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.ItemId", "AdId":"@item.Header.Id"}'
                               class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="delete d-print-none">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.Id", "AdId":"@item.Id"}'
                               class="open-delete btn btn-primary" href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:15px;color:red" id="delete" name="delete"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="edit d-print-none">
                            <a data-toggle="modal"
                               data-id='{"id": "@item.Items.Number","ItemId":"@item.Items.ItemId", "AdId":"@item.Header.Id"}'
                               class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Page @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)- @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Business)</div>
                    <div class="row mb-2 font-weight-bold">
                        <div class="col-md-6">Cut: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Number)</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">9-Box: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.BoxNumber)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-2 font-weight-bold">
                        <div class="col-md-4">Group @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Test)</div>
                        @*<div class="col-md-4">Div: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Division)</div>*@
                        <div class="col-md-4">Buyer @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Test)</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">Dept @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Department)</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
        }
</div>
```

Lets say you want two image display items per page then you can use css as follows

```
@media screen and (max-width: 8000px) {
    .gridContainer

{
    display: grid;
    background-color: #Whatever;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto; //This determines the number of grid-items per row (one auto per item)
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: #Whatever;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I like this method of creating page breaks since its easy to modify if you want to change the number of items per row.